# Two Python packages with the same name: How to pick the right one?

Tags: python, package

I am creating a package that depends on the [`python-gnupg`](https://pypi.org/project/python-gnupg/) PyPi package. In Python it is imported as `gnupg`.
It is installed during the setup of my package.

Unfortunately there is the [`gnupg`](https://pypi.org/project/gnupg/) PyPi package which is also imported as `gnupg` in Python.

How do I make sure that the right package is called when I run `from gnupg import ...`? I want my package to work for users who have already installed the 'wrong' `gnupg` in their Python distribution and now have both packages residing in their site-packages directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load a module by its full path. That way you are sure which one is loaded:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module.name", "/path/to/file.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
```

Taken from: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: Is it possible to make this a bit more flexible? Instead of specifying an absolute path, can I tell importlib: 'Import whatever `gnupg` you find on the path, but only consider packages that have `python-gnupg` in their name'?